# How do I throw a javascript error for iOS evaluateJavaScript to catch it?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, error-handling

In `evaluateJavaScript` I call a javascript function that fetches an array of objects. If it fails, it calls a `handleError` function that throws an error.

I know that the `handleError` function is being called (I have a console.log statement) but when I throw an error, `evaluateJavaScript` is not capturing it.

Here's what I'm doing:

In my `.swift` file:

```
evaluateJavaScript("window.sampleFunctionThatHandlesFetch()", completionHandler: {(_ result: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
            print("result: \(result)")
            print("error: \(error)")
})
```

`error` is always nil.

In the `.js` file:

```
var handleError = function handleError(errorText) {
         throw new Error(errorText);
};
```

How can I throw the error for `evaluateJavaScript` to capture it inside `error`?

Comment: it should be window.sampleFunctionThatHandlesFetch() right, otherwise you are not executing the function..

Comment: Yeah, I was changing the name of the function for stack overflow and forgot to add that. The function is being executed 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can suggest is just posting a message to your webView. That is, of course, if you're using `WKWebView` to display web content.

To do so you need to adopt `WKScriptMessageHandler` by the class you have your `WKWebView` instance declared in.

Then you need to modify web view's initialization to use custom configuration with required message handler:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.add(self, name: "aMessageHandler")        
config.userContentController = contentController
yourWKWebViewInstance = WKWebView(frame: someCGRect, configuration: config)
```

After doing so you will be able to receive messages through this function

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)
{
    if message.name == "aMessageHandler"
    {
        let yourMessage = message.body as? String
        // Do whatever you need to do with it
    }
}
```

And to post this message in JS you need to invoke `postMessage` method like so:

```
var handleError = function handleError(errorText) {
     window.webkit.messageHandlers.aMessageHandler.postMessage(errorText);
};
```